# Pyspark - Schema validation using Metadata

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to validate the data using spark schema. I would like to know what are the different metadata tags that I can pass to the struct field

**col1** - accepts "**val1**", "**val2**", ....(A column accepts only few legal values. If any other value appears in that column that should be a bad record)

Is there any tag that I can use in the StructField to validate the data while reading the source file?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data you're working with and the output you expect when legal or illegal values show up?

Answer (score 0):

As of Spark 3.3.0 does not provide column value validation during read.
StructField **metadata** parameters serves more like [tagging feature](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.StructType.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType.add).

You will need to write your own validation rules. One way would be to use **filter** like below.

```
    def validate_val(negated: bool = False):
        negate = "not " if negated else ""
        return expr(f" {negate} startswith(c1, 'val') ")

    all_records = spark.createDataFrame([["val1", "val2"], ["not_val1", "val2"]], ["c1", "c2"]) 
    good_records = all_records.filter(validate_val())
    bad_records = all_records.filter(validate_val(negated=True))
```

Also you would probably need to
`all_records.cache()`
to avoid data reload for each action i.e. bad_records.count() etc.

Full code:

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test-app").master("local[1]").getOrCreate()

    def validate_val(negated: bool = False):
        negate = "not " if negated else ""
        return expr(f" {negate} startswith(c1, 'val') ")

    all_records = spark.createDataFrame([["val1", "val2"], ["not_val1", "val2"]], ["c1", "c2"])
    all_records = all_records.cache()    
    good_records = all_records.filter(validate_val())
    bad_records = all_records.filter(validate_val(negated=True))
    good_records.show()
    bad_records.show()
    all_records.show()

+----+----+
|  c1|  c2|
+----+----+
|val1|val2|
+----+----+

+--------+----+
|      c1|  c2|
+--------+----+
|not_val1|val2|
+--------+----+

+--------+----+
|      c1|  c2|
+--------+----+
|    val1|val2|
|not_val1|val2|
+--------+----+
```